# Black area on UIWebView during load

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I noticed that my `UITabBar` gets a dark-gray color when I preform `loadRequest` in my `UIWebView`.

If I scroll my `WebView` during `loadRequest` there is a black area

[image]  [image]

How can I remove this?

Comment: @Chan It loads just fine, it's just during loading i get this.

Comment: [This is the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41780512/1223728)

Answer (score 34):

I've had this problem before, and it's related to the content inset of your UIWebView. This black area appears wherever you have a bottom inset set on the scrollview. I was able to fix this by setting the `opaque` property of the webview:

```
self.opaque = NO;
```

Answer (score 18):

Set for UIWebView opaque NO and clear background color simultaneously:

[image]

Comment: The clear color is unnecessary. White should suffice and be more performant.

Comment: Thanks for a complete answer.
@KyleClegg if you wanted to have a clear background can used clear color or other colour. this need to be explain because some new coder dosent even understand how it actually work.

Comment: p/s i found a dark gray color on my webview. with an empty text in black color.
Background colour for the webview will help either to make a default white background or clear color

Answer (score 9):

You need to set the background color to clear as well as making the webView opaque.  This doesn't seem to work if you don't also change the backgroundColor to clear.

```
self.opaque = NO;
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

I must disagree with the suggested solutions here. The recommended solution of setting the `opaque` and `backgroudColor` silently hides the real problem. If you do that, then the front-most `UIWebBrowserView` won't cover the entire frame with the black rectangle, and will be transparent -> but the area that was previously black will remain unused, and your content **won't be displayed there**.

I extracted the **UIWebBrowserView** and printed out its descriptions when resizing, and it seems to me that it **uses rounded values for its content rectangle**. As the view's frame bounds are defined as `CGFloat` you get rounding issues when you scale the web browser view window (resizing the wrapping view's height/width to a non-integral values).

I managed to fix this problem through rounding the `setFrame` arguments of my `UIWebView`:

```
UIWebView *myWebView;
....
[myWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(newX, newY, floor(newWidth), floor(newHeight)];
```

Answer (score 2):

In swift,

webView.opaque = false