# Grey bar on top of UIWebView in iOS 10

Tags: ios, uiwebview

When I drag a UIWebView from the Object Library in Xcode, I get a UIWebView with this dark grey bar at the top:

[image]

What is that and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 10):

You need put `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` in ViewDidLoad

The other choice is disable option **Adjust Scroll View Insets** in the .xib of your viewcontroller

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That dark grey color is the background color set for the UIWebView. This will show if a webpage is smaller than the frame of the web view. You won't see it if you change the background color to white or transparent.

Answer (score -1):

`_webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`

This should work if you have a WKWebView/UITableView/ScrollView. Add this in ViewDidLoad. This will make the status bar overlap the content without adding a extra white space in the status bar.